# Find and Replace text in XML tags in Unix

Tags: xml, shell, unix, awk, sed

I need to change date format in XML tags. I have written awk to find-replace date format in command line - `echo '2012-01-13' | awk -v FS=- -v OFS=/ '{print $2,$3,$1}'` . But not sure how to proceed with using this in XML..

**XML used**

```
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>1986-09-03</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.133</LastUpdated>
```

Need to change DoB format across XML.

**Expected Output:**

```
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>09/03/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.133</LastUpdated>
```

Comment: Don't do that. If the input is valid XML (which your example is not), then use an XML-aware tool like `xmlstarlet` or `xsltproc`. Secondly, you should not convert a perfectly good date format into a stupid date format.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do, provided the `<DateOfBirth>` tag and date are on same line

```
$ cat ip.xml
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>1986-09-03</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.133</LastUpdated>

$ sed -E '/<DateOfBirth>/ s|([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})|\2/\3/\1|' ip.xml 
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>09/03/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.133</LastUpdated>
```

- `-E` extended regex option
- `/<DateOfBirth>/` substitute only on lines matching `<DateOfBirth>`
- `([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})` extract date with numbers alone captured
- `\2/\3/\1` required output format

This might work if extended regex option is not available:

```
sed '/<DateOfBirth>/ s|\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)|\2/\3/\1|' ip.xml
```

Similar solution with `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's|(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|$2/$3/$1| if /<DateOfBirth>/' ip.xml 
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>09/03/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.133</LastUpdated>
```

Comment: I guess my bash is old. sed -E ain't working.. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @Siva, in that case, it is better to add which sed version you have and may be which OS too.. would a perl solution be okay? would be very similar to sed

Comment: @Siva, I've also added a solution without `-E` option, can you check if that works?

Comment: Thanks Sundeep, the second one worked. Thanks a ton :) Didn't try perl.

Comment: @Siva, glad that worked, don't forget to accept the answer which worked the best for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is `awk` version: This will check for the string "DateOfBirth". If this string is seen then extract the date and then  format it.  use `sub` to replace date with modified date.

```
awk -F'<|>' '/DateOfBirth/{split($3,a,"-");sub($3, a[2]"/"a[3]"/"a[1])}1' xml
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>09/03/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.133</LastUpdated>
```

*Note: Use some XML aware tool. warned.*